# How to implement Ember-Validations in Ember-App-Kit With Out Fixtures

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, ember-app-kit

This is a **NEAR** duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194889/how-to-implement-ember-validations-in-ember-app-kiteak) which has a very nice example of ember-validations (without EAK) [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iDeQABo/34/edit). However, I am wondering if anybody can do an EAK version of this for me, with the one difference that the JSBIN has validation errors shown only once the user has blurred a form input. This jsbin shows the errors on load. I would expect to see the validation messages come after the field has been focused for the first time at the very soonest, rather than onload. Im not sure if this is an artifact of JSBIN implementation or the actual expected feature design of ember-validations. I would love to see a clean EAK in git or bitbucket that has just this, the same 5 or 6 inputs in the index.hbs that are tied to a controller with the same five elements in the validations object, but the difference that it doesn't show errors until after the controls are at least interacted with once by the user. I would be extra happy to see the steps the user took at the terminal to add ember-validations to their EAK, because currently, I'm following this study below and I am unsure if perhaps the problem is not the EAK implementation, but rather the manner in which I've brought the ember-validations.js into my app in the first place. I've had some conflicting suggestions on how this should be done, but considering that right now, I have at least seen error messages in the page it's hard to tell if there's a problem with the way the script is included or not.

```
gem install bundler
git clone git://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations.git
cd ember-validations
bundle install
bundle exec rake dist
cp dist/ember-validations/ember-validations.js vendor/ember-validations/ember-validations.js
subl app/index.html

insert line 57:     <script src="/vendor/ember-validations/ember-validations.js"></script>
open http://localhost:8000
```

With this, I am able to see the errors highlighted when the app loads. However, for my attempt, I don't see the errors clear or the continue button enabled after satisfactory input is added. So I am having the same unwanted functionality as the JSBIN and the OP. This maybe a more basic ember js question, or a basic EAK question, but I would love to see a simple ember-validations set up in EAK(ES6) format. With a list of files, their locations, or better still a git to clone.

Also, I am looking to see this done without FIXTURES or DS store if possible. I am thinking a simple object in the controller. It appears to me in the documentation that as soon as the object is created, validation fires. So, how to defer the validation until after the form-controls are interacted with?

Thanks!

Edit: So, I was able to get the EAK architecture to happen... anybody interested in my solution, there's [a bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/Dr0ss/eak-ember-validations/src) now for you to inspect and enjoy!

Edit 2: So, looking and thinking about this some more. It makes sense the way it is. It's only my styling and message language that makes it clunky. Of course the presence: property makes them seem like errors, but they are in fact, also hypostatized as cta's or call to actions, highlighting fields that need attention. When the fields are empty initially, instead of thinking about them like errors, think about them like attention getting call outs. Since my button is disabled as long as the fields are inValid, there's no reason to have the messages at any other time, since there will never be a use case in which the user has submitted the button without satisfying the presence and other properties of the validations object. So, to solve my "problem" I just need to think about the errors differently. Instead of styling them with an error class, I'll style them normally, and when presence is satisfied, show a checkmark or something friendly like that. So in effect, these validations are working as I want them to. It's just a matter of not following the out-of-the-box nature of the message error styling.

Double Thanks!